# Hazelcast lookup null value

Tags: java, predicate, hazelcast

Does anybody know how to lookup null value object in Hazelcast?
I use predicate, but predicate doesn't allow to pass any null value. It's not a string type in Hazelcast, it's a Date type. So I cannot pass empty string. 
Hazelcast seems not support null value lookup. 
Any awesome people knows how to do that?
Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but in a IMap you can't have a null value so it doesn't make sense to me.

If you really need to have a null value, please consider using a null token, for example the string 'null'. This is how you can simulate a null value; but you need to take care of translating that string to null where appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for response. I'm using SqlPredicate to build the search restriction. The column I look for is date type, and some of date column have null value in HazelCast. I try to pass,  for example "startFrom=NULL" or "null", to HazelCast. When I use this string to build up SqlPredicate, it complaints NULL or null is not correct data type. My question is that is there any way I can look up null value in HazelCast?